# Highest ocurrence in a list if some elements repeat the same times

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to write a function that receives a list and return an list of the most repeated element. My problem is that the function i wrote just return one repeated element and i need all the most repeated elements (if they repeat the same times). In the example I put the function needs to return *diamonds*, *spades*, but the result i have just return *diamonds*

```
def getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind): 
    counter = 0
    num = listAnyKind[0] 
      
    for i in listAnyKind: 
        frequency = listAnyKind.count(i) 
        if (frequency > counter): 
            counter = frequency 
            num = i 
  
    return num 
  

listAnyKind = ['diamonds', 'spades', 'spades', 'clubs','hearts', 'diamonds'] 
    
print(getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use `Counter` from the collections module:

```
from collections import Counter

def getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind):
    c = Counter(listAnyKind)
    m = max(c.values())
    return [k for k in c if c[k] == m]

listAnyKind = ['diamonds', 'spades', 'spades', 'clubs','hearts', 'diamonds'] 
print(getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind))
```

Output:

```
['diamonds', 'spades']
```

Comment: Please avoid finding max value every time in the iteration.

Comment: FYI, this answer is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind):
   highest_count = 0  
   checked = []
   return_items = []
   for i in listAnyKind:
      if i in checked:
         continue
      else: 
         count = listAnyKind.count(i)
      if count > highest_count:
         highest_count = count
         return_items = [i]
      elif count == highest_count:
         return_items.append(i)
      checked.append(i)
   return return_items
listAnyKind = ['diamonds', 'spades', 'spades', 'clubs','hearts', 'diamonds'] 
print(getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind))
```

Here is an alternative solution that isn't as efficient as using counter from the collections module but can be done this way

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
def getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind): 
    counter = 0
    num = listAnyKind[0] 
    frequency = {}  
    for i in set(listAnyKind): 
        frequency[i] = listAnyKind.count(i) 
     
    return [k for k in frequency if frequency[k] == max(frequency.values())]
  

listAnyKind = ['diamonds', 'spades', 'spades', 'clubs','hearts', 'diamonds'] 

print(getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind))
```

Answer (score 0):

use a dictionary to store the item name in it and it's  frequency in it

```
def getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind): 
    dic = {}
    for item in listAnyKind:
        if item not in dic:
            dic[item] = 1
        else:
            dic[item]+=1
    max_occu = max(dic.values())
    
    max_item = [k for k, v in dic.items() if v==max_occu]
    return max_item

listAnyKind = ['diamonds', 'spades', 'spades', 'clubs','hearts', 'diamonds'] 
    
print(getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind))
```

output

```
['diamonds', 'spades']
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is another short and fast way to go. You find the frequency of elements and then return the ones with the highest frequency:

```
import numpy as np
def getHighestOcurrence(listAnyKind): 
    u, freq = np.unique(listAnyKind, return_counts=True)
    return u[np.argwhere(freq==freq.max())].ravel().tolist()
```

output:

```
['diamonds', 'spades']
```